# How to save a non-blurry, high quality image of a control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a DrawingContext to draw images. I then render the result to a RenderTargetBitmap. The image is crisp & sharp on the screen, but becomes blurred when saved. Even on 100% scaling the issue persists. Interesting part is that if the image width is less than 2000px it exports fine. But as the width increases, exported image keeps getting more and more blur.

Here is my code ( [Sample project](https://github.com/dotriz/ImageExportWPF) )

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"image-full-hd.png");
            bitmap.EndInit();
            img1.Source = bitmap;

            img1.Width = bitmap.Width;
            img1.Height= bitmap.Height;
        }

        private void btnExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = CaptureSnapshot(img1);
            Clipboard.SetImage(result);
        }

        public BitmapSource CaptureSnapshot(UIElement source)
        {
            var dpi = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(source);
            double dpiX = dpi.DpiScaleX, dpiY = dpi.DpiScaleY;

            double newImageWidth = source.RenderSize.Width * dpiX;
            double newImageHeight = source.RenderSize.Height * dpiY;

            RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)newImageWidth, (int)newImageHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

            using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                VisualBrush sourceBrush1 = new VisualBrush(source)
                {
                    Stretch = Stretch.None
                };

                context.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush1, null, new Rect(source.RenderSize));
            }

            System.Windows.Size s1size = new System.Windows.Size(newImageWidth, newImageHeight);
            source.Measure(s1size); 
            source.Arrange(new Rect(s1size));

            RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(renderTarget, EdgeMode.Unspecified);
            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(renderTarget, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
            renderTarget.Render(visual);

            return renderTarget;
        }
```

**Application Window**
[image]

**Clip from an Exported Image which was 3400px wide**
[image]

Comment: I may be a bit disconnected, but what's the problem with this simple code https://pastebin.com/raw/Njqx9HnB

Comment: @SimonMourier - tested your code with the provided demo https://github.com/dotriz/ImageExportWPF and it does give better result

Comment: @SimonMourier - here a side by side comparison of OPs code and yours - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHe4l.png

Comment: @RandRandom - yes, I tested it too :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier Your code does not draw a scaled copy of the source element into the bitmap, which OP apparently wants to do in order create a screenshot with higher pixel density. You could however achieve the same result by using dpi.PixelsPerInchX and dpi.PixelsPerInchY instead of 96 for the DPIs of the RenderTargetBitmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source UIElement has already been rendered - and you are using its `RenderSize` for calculating the size of the bitmap - there is no need for another layout pass, so the Measure and Arrange calls seem unnecessary.

In order to create an unblurred DrawingVisual output of the scaled original image, you could directly draw the `ImageSource` of the Image element into the Visual when the `source` argument is an Image. Use a VisualBrush only when `source` is not an Image.

```
public static BitmapSource CaptureSnapshot(UIElement source)
{
    var dpi = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(source);
    var width = source.RenderSize.Width * dpi.DpiScaleX;
    var height = source.RenderSize.Height * dpi.DpiScaleY;
    var rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    var visual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (var context = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        if (source is Image image)
        {
            context.DrawImage(image.Source, rect);
        }
        else
        {
            context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(source), null, rect);
        }
    }

    bitmap.Render(visual);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Measure and Arrange calls help capturing the whole control when there's a scrollbar or non visible area. Otherwise it only renders the visible part.

This code gives same blurry output. Did you try any ultra HD image, like something 3800x2000?

I have updated main question how I load image in the image control.

Comment: I just created a 3500x3500 test image from an ItemsControl with a UniformGrid with 100x100 Rectangles with StrokeThickness 1. The ItemsControl sets UseLayoutRounding and SnapToDevicePixel to true.

Comment: I also have UseLayoutRounding="True", RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality", RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" - What could be the issue of blurry output?

Comment: FYI, Here's my sample project https://github.com/dotriz/ImageExportWPF

Comment: @Riz - move `UseLayoutRounding="True"` to the window instead of image

Comment: @Riz - read the remarks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks - `You should set UseLayoutRounding to true on the root element.`

Comment: @Riz Please see the rewritten answer. As a note, this method works without Measure and Arrange in your sample application.

Comment: @RandRandom I had UseLayoutRounding on root element too, but it didn't make any difference. It seems to be rendering issue with UIElements of high resolution with Visual Brushes. That's why DrawImage with image.source has 100% correct quality as compared to DrawRectangle with VisualBrush & BitmapCacheBrush

Comment: If any future reader can not use DrawImage with image.source, try @legkov-ivan suggestion to use BitmapCacheBrush brush which gives better quality than VisualBrush

Answer (score 3):

Is there a need for using `DrawingVisual`, `DrawingContext` and `VisualBrush`? Because if not, you can just pass the `UIElement` directly to `RenderTargetBitmap.Render()`. I cloned your sample project and changed `CaptureSnapshot` to this:

```
public BitmapSource CaptureSnapshot(UIElement source)
{
    var dpi = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(source);
    var width = source.RenderSize.Width * dpi.DpiScaleX;
    var height = source.RenderSize.Height * dpi.DpiScaleY;

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)height,
        dpi.PixelsPerInchX, dpi.PixelsPerInchY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    Size s1size = new Size(width, height);
    source.Measure(s1size);
    source.Arrange(new Rect(s1size));

    bitmap.Render(source);

    return bitmap;
}
```

And the result does not appear blurry for both sample images in the project.

## EDIT

Since using `Visual` is required I did some more search and discovered [this thread](https://www.telerik.com/forums/low-resolution-using-exporttoimage-on-big-diagram). You can use `BitmapCacheBrush` with `SnapsToDevicePixels` set to `true` and it should work without the blur:

```
using (var context = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    var vb = new BitmapCacheBrush(source)
    {
        BitmapCache = new BitmapCache { SnapsToDevicePixels = true}
    };
    context.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
}
```

Comment: Yes, its important to do *DrawingVisual* and render the *visual* object instead of source. Because there's some other code too which adds markups on top of the source image which finally is rendered and exported.

Comment: @Riz Found another way around this issue, edited my answer, see if it works for you

Comment: BitmapCacheBrush creates a good result. When drawing a scaled rectangle with a Brush (instead of the source element), the RenderTargetBitmap must have DPIs of 96 to get the scaling correctly. The rectangle would otherwise not fit into the bitmap if DPI scaling is not 100%